# VBA - How to search Active Workbooks, and match a filename against string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am coding up a quick automation project for work, I cannot specify a filepath to open a workbook from as it is used in a special software, not easily accessible with VBA.

If User A opens this file: "ABC_todaysdate"... How would I tell Excel to cycle through the active workbooks (User A could have 5-6 workbooks open), find the letter ABC in the Activeworkbook filename, and use that in the rest of my function?

VBA Code so far:

```
Sub CopyDemand()
Dim filename As String
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each Wb2 In Application.Workbooks
filename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
If filename Like "demand" Then
Debug.Print ("Found")
''' Insert function to use WB2 and copy over data, compare workbooks etc.
Next
Wb.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: You lack of clarity (I am not sure to understand what you want to do) and you did not provide us with what you have tried so far (if you tried anything).

Comment: Please edit your question and post you code in it.

Comment: Edited OP post, thanks! I am fairly new here to the formatting and everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate each workbook, however I think the key here is to make the workbook active so you can retrieve the FullName with the path information.

```
Option Explicit

Function getWbName(SearchStr As String) As String
On Error GoTo ErrHand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook

    getWbName = vbNullString

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, wb.Name, SearchStr, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            wb.Activate
            getWbName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Return the active window and exit
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Function

ErrHand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox (Err.Number & " has occured, with description: " & Err.Description)
End Function

Sub Example()
    Debug.Print getWbName("Book2")
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Updated the code above to return the WorkBook Object instead.

```
Option Explicit

Function getWorkBookByName(SearchStr As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, wb.Name, SearchStr, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set getWorkBookByName = wb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub Example()
    Dim myWb As Workbook: Set myWb = getWorkBookByName("Book2")
    If Not myWb Is Nothing Then Debug.Print myWb.FullName
End Sub
```

Comment: This works wonderfully as well, Its more geared to what I was trying to achieve. I presume after the If statement, once I find the InStr search, I can assign this "WB" to a Public variable and use it in the "Sub Example" method?

Comment: You could, or just make the function return a WorkBook object instead. I understood your requirements to return the Path to the WorkBook object, however returning the Workbook object works too. Just change `getWbName(SearchStr As String) As String` to `getWbName(SearchStr As String) As Workbook` and `getWbName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName` to `getWbName = wb`. Also remove the `wb.Activate` and `ThisWorkbook.Activate` and `getWbName = vbNullString` lines

Comment: Ah, that should work out perfectly then. I'll give this a try, was working on a way of trying to figure this out all day yesterday. I learned quite a bit from your comments. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just tried this, for some reason in the 'sub example

Comment: Just tried this, in the 'sub example'
I tried to say 'getWbName.activate' and 'msgbox ("Done") to test to see if I was passing the getWbName over, but I keep running into a "argument not optional" error

Comment: Ahh I saw your edit now, I understand why it was not working. In your Sub Example (unsure of how to make the text grey like you did), Are you referencing "Book2" as simply a dummy reference? or is there a reason behind that?

Comment: One of my open workbooks is 'Book2', you'd change that to the Workbook you want to find.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your help! I ended up changing 'Book2" to blank ("") as the searchStr already finds the match and the Function contains the Workbook I instead to use.

Comment: Hey Ryan, 

I had posted this on another forum as well and this solution works too, figured you'd like to see a different way of doing this method. I'll be using your way though :)

    'Sub Test()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each Wb2 In Application.Workbooks
        If Wb2.Name Like "Demand*" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Wb2

    If Wb2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Weekly workbook not found"
    Else
        Wb2.Activate
        MsgBox ("Done")
    End If

End Sub'

Answer (score 0):

You can try to capture the [WorkbookOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196583.aspx) event of the Application object.

Here is a way to do so: copy the following code into the `ThisWorkbook` object of your main workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents myApp As Application

Private Sub myApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "Openned " & Wb.FullName
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set myApp = Application
End Sub
```

Then close you workbook and reopen if with macro enabled. The name of this workbook and each subsequent workbook openned whil it is open will be shown in a message box.

Comment: Wow! thanks Vincent, I wasn't aware of setting a workbook open catcher, I really like this idea. Could I declare this a public function and use variables in other Modules of ThisWorkbook, or is it isolated only to "thisWorkbook"

Comment: Well, `Application` is available everywhere, the only use here of myApp is catch the WorkbookOpen event in order to be alerted when the user opens a workbook. From the event you will then be able to call any function you want or set any variable you need to process. The objective here is to not have to look periodically for new opened workbook to test. You can also catch the event the same way in other object or class modules.