# Selection open Workbooks by partial name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to select open workbook when name of it is not constant. Lets say name for the file is "File 123 Name" and number part is changing daily. Tomorrow it could be "File 124 Name", day after "File 145 Name", etc.

Is there any way to select it by regexp or something else? I'm currently using `Windows("File 456 Name").Activate` method. Essentially VBA code needs to match open workbook by some predefined pattern. Also it should return error if two open files are matching the same pattern.

Comment: There may be a better example than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001133/vba-how-to-search-active-workbooks-and-match-a-filename-against-string) but I think it's helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to `Select` or `Activate` it?  Just iterate through the open workbooks and, when you find a match, set a workbook variable to that workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Somthing like this ?**

```
Sub Macro1()

For Each wb In Workbooks

    If InStr(1, wb.Name, "File") > 0 And InStr(1, wb.Name, "Name") > 0 Then

        Debug.Print wb.Name

    End If

Next

End Sub
```